# Get the MAC address of bluetooth adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get the MAC address of bluetooth in my android device. So I'm using the following method:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String macAddress = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

The address returned is `02:00:00:00:00:00`. I've seen questions and posts saying that it's not possible anymore to get your MAC address in android unless your application is a **System Application**.

So what if I really need to get the MAC address of my phone?? It's impossible to do it or what?

**Note:** I know this question is asked lots of times on SO, but most of the answers are out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [Youssif Saeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2215147/youssif-saeed) said in the other answer was correct. Android won't let us get the MAC address anymore.

Brief description about what I want:

Let's say I have a phone with MAC Address X, and I have another nearby device with MAC address B. When the two devices are nearby each other. I was able to get the MAC address of the other device using BluetoothDevice and getAddress() method from ScanResult.getDevice(). So what I still need is to catch my own device MAC address so that in the backend I save each user with his MAC address, and when I catch it in bluetooth, I know who's nearby me

Here's the workaround I've done in order to send some data between near devices.

I found something called [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview). It is available for Android and iOS and very easy to implement. Now I'm able to catch near devices with my application installed on them, and send a unique Id generated by the application to identify the user.

Answer (score 6):

For security reasons this functionality is not available on Android since Android version 6.0 [[source]](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id):-

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods
>   now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

The reason for this is to stop random applications gaining information about the phone's hardware addresses therefore violating the privacy/data protection.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So what if someone need the MAC address? Like is it impossible? There's no workaround?

Comment: Yes it was made impossible because it can be an attack vector. The only workaround I can think of is if you downgrade your OS to pre Android v6.0. Why do you need your mac address? There might be another way to achieve what you want without accessing the mac address.

Comment: Let's say I have a phone with MAC Address X, and I have another nearby device with MAC address B. When the two devices are nearby each other. I was able to get the MAC address of the other device using `BluetoothDevice` and `getAddress()` method from `ScanResult.getDevice()`. So what I still need is to catch my own device MAC address so that in the backend I save each user with his MAC address, and when I catch it in bluetooth, I know who's nearby me. I really don't know if I made myself clear it;s a little bit complicated to explain, sorry for the long comment.

Comment: I think I understand your application, but as you can imagine this would be undesirable for Google because your app will know the location of any user that comes in close range with you, therefore violating their privacy. Have a look at this article which explains something a bit similar to your idea and its challenges:- https://wyldnetworks.com/wyld-mesh-covid-19-proximity-contact-tracing/

Comment: Is there any other way then to fingerprint a device for access control?

Comment: Does this "security" also apply to company-managed devices (work profile etc)? I cannot find any confirmation that it doesn't, in which case Google gives the corporate users the finger, again. Here we were, in a fully managed work environment, trying to show a bluetooth pairing barcode on the screen, to pair the phone with a wireless barcode scanner that supports this type of pairing. And we needed to encode the phone's bluetooth address into the barcode for that...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my device for bluetooth and wifi mac.
Some properties are not hidden .
If you run getprop on an unrooted shell inside your application, you might find these properties which are read only:

persist.odm.wifimac: [xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]

persist.odm.bt.address: [xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]

For my application, i run this command to get the bluetooth mac and then i read the content back from the datainputstream to get the mac adress.

getprop persist.odm.bt.address